# Can a function be uniformly continuous on an open interval?

Tags: analysis

I am learning analysis and all the uniformly continuous functions I have seen are over a closed interval. So, can a uniformly continuous function be defined on an open interval?

Comment: Sure it can, a simple example is the function $f(x)=x$ on the interval $(0,1)$. You should try to rigorously prove why this is indeed uniformly continuous

Comment: Hmmm... $f(x)=0$ for every $x$.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Absolute continuity on an open interval of the real line?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4426/absolute-continuity-on-an-open-interval-of-the-real-line)

Comment: Uniformly continuity definition doesn't depends of domain, just restrict it.

Answer (score 9):

This result may help you:

Let ${F}:(a, b)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is continuous on the bounded open interval $(a, b)$ then the two limits given by

$F(a +) = \lim_{x\to a^{+}} F(x)$,  $F(b -) = \lim_{x\to b^{-}} F(x)$ exists iff $F$ is uniformly continuous on $(a, b)$.

This result has been given in the book **"The calculus integral by Brian S. Thomson".**

Comment: Nice result....

Comment: @GastónBurrull Thanks ..... :)

Answer (score 5):

Sure, take a function which is continuous on a finite closed interval, and remove the endpoints.

And there are many functions defined on the whole real line that are uniformly continuous.

Comment: Do you mean remove the endpoints of a continuous function or a uniformly continuous function?

Comment: A function continuous on a closed bounded interval **is** uniformly continuous in that interval.

Comment: Oh right! Thanks..I felt dumb...

Comment: Just an oversight. Sorry to be so competitive, but I'll bet I have had many more of them than you.